# Does an action with the "Press" trait require that you use it on the same target of your initial attack?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, fighter, traits

The rules for the ["Press" trait](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=675) read as follows (emphasis mine):

> Actions with this trait allow you to follow up earlier attacks. An action with the press trait can be used only if you are **currently affected by a multiple attack penalty**. You can’t use a press action when it’s not your turn, even if you use the Ready activity.

The first sentence implies that this trait represents special attacks which involve *repeated* blows, but it doesn't clarify if it has to be against the first target you attack on your turn.

For example, imagine that I'm a fighter with the [Combat Grab](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=4780&NoRedirect=1) feat: if I'm facing two goblins, and I attack goblin #1 (which would give me a multiple attack penalty), can I use Combat Grab against goblin #2 even though I haven't yet attacked them?

Answer (score 11):

### There is no target restriction with *Press*

If an ability requires that you target the same thing twice, it explicitly says so. For example [Bear Hug](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=2275):

> **Requirements** The bear’s last action was a successful claw Strike.
> The bear makes another claw Strike *against the same target*. If this Strike hits, the target is also grabbed, as if the bear had successfully Grappled the target.